# How to duplicate Row in Datagridview with Button

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

[image]

I have a DataGridView with a column which is filled with buttons. Now I want that with every click on the button the selected row in the DataGridView is copied and inserted directly behind the selected row. But: I only want to duplicate the value of 2 specific columns. And between this two specific columns one should be counted with numbers from 1 starting manually typed in to 2, 3, 4 and so on with every click on the duplicate button. The other columns should be empty. How can I realize this ?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Show some code that did you so far to achieve your result?

Comment: You can not add rows to the gridview. You can add new item or row to the underlying data source to which grid view is bound.

Comment: @er-sho: I have no code tho show because it´s simply a datagridview made with the designer in Visual Studio

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya: You can add rows to the GridView (AllowUserstoAddRows)

Comment: @Adir To rephrase er-sho: *What did you try?*

Comment: @OhBeWise I have try many functions but on luck because i have no clue how to do this and nothing worked. Maybe you can help me to start first with only duplicating the specific row into the DataGridView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope it does the job

```
// Enable AllowUserToAddRows
dgv.AllowUserToAddRows = true;

    private void dgv_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridView dgv = sender as DataGridView;

        // If button clicked
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 0)
        {
            // Get values what you want to use, the Cell 2 is already increased
            var value1 = dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value;
            var value2 = dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value;

            // Define the maximum id and the row index of it
            int maxId = Convert.ToInt32(value2);
            int latestRowIndex = e.RowIndex;

            for (int i = 0; i < dgv.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                // Select the highest id of selected item and get its row index
                if (dgv.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value == value1)
                {
                    maxId = Convert.ToInt32(dgv.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);
                    latestRowIndex = i;
                }
            }

            // Insert a new row behind max id one
            dgv.Rows.Insert(latestRowIndex + 1);

            // Set the previously stored values and increase the stored Cell 2 value
            dgv.Rows[latestRowIndex + 1].Cells[1].Value = value1;
            dgv.Rows[latestRowIndex + 1].Cells[2].Value = maxId + 1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks alot! This worked very well. I have another question. I want that the value of a specific cell is increasing with every klick on the button. For Example: if the value of cell 2 is 1. I want that with every klick within this function the value of that specific row ist counting up to 2 and with the next duplicated row to 3. Can you help me?

Comment: You're welcome. Answer is edited to the new question.

Comment: @Joszef  I have a small problem. First i hat to convert it to int because of format exception. I´ve done this with Convert.ToInt32 and it worked. With a little bit custimization youre code works very well but i only have one problem. If i start with the first row now it works and increases by 1 every time. But it goe´s in my Table in the wrong direction. So if i increase 5 times the first row Cell 2 is showing :5, 4, 3, 2, 1. So i only need to show it in other direction. How can i do this? Many thanks again!

Comment: Please see the edited answer. If it's not the proper answer please let me know.

Comment: Sadly its not the answer. Like i´ve said before in that version of your code it starts counting from 3 and with my edited version it starts from one but something hast to change to show the 1 in the first row and with the next row 2 and so on. The output must be exactly the other way round to show it beginning from first row 1 and second row added 2 third row 3 and so on. In this case i start with entering 1 into the cell and but if i click my button 1 is entered in the second line of row and the first row ist increasing to 2.

Comment: Sorry, but it's not clear. Can you please send me table how you mean?

Comment: Please, upload and link a photo of the result what you need and I will edit the answer to it.

Comment: I´ve uploaded the post with an actual image of the result. The Grey button on the side is my column filled with buttons. So i want to start with entering Pencil in cell one. Then i want to duplicate it which works with your code. But i also want to count up for pencil like i´ve drawn in the uploaded photo. In this way the user doesnt have to enter every Time pencil and the number of the pencil. By the way pencil is only en example value.

Comment: Now if you click any row it will find the max id of item and insert the new row behind it. Please find the edited answer. If you have further questions, let me know.

Comment: Jozsef thank you very much four your help mate. You were the only one who solved the problem!  It worked! Sorry for the late reply i wasn´t working on the application for a few days. Thank´s alot again my friend!

Comment: I'm glad I could help! :) Have a great day!